# What are Boba Fett's most prominent appearences?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, boba-fett

I just finished watching Star Wars in the [Machete Order](https://www.nomachetejuggling.com/2011/11/11/the-star-wars-saga-suggested-viewing-order/) (Episodes IV, V, II, III and finally VI)

Before this, I had heard numerous references to Boba Fett and he seemed extremely popular. There was even talk of his own spinoff movie. But, disappointingly, he didn't have a lot of screen time in the original Trilogy.

Since he is so popular, I'd like to know Which Star Wars Legends properties feature Boba Fett in a prominent role?

Comment: It's worth noting that Fett *did* have a fairly major Expanded Universe presence, but that was *because* he was so popular, not the other way around

Comment: @JasonBaker: If there is no such property, this question would be off-topic, right? Should I take it down?

Comment: @Area51DetectiveFiction : The piece of your question regarding Fett's appearance in the Expanded Universe is fine and can be answered explicitly, but your question about the *reason* for his popularity (which I interpret to be your *main* one) is both too broad and too opinion-based.  This site tends to prefer questions that can garner specific answers that can be backed up by references to specific works.  Discussing Boba Fett's popularity would mostly be speculation and theory --- better for the site's chat room, Mos Eisley.  I would reword your question, taking these concerns into account.

Comment: @Praxis: Better now?

Comment: @Area51DetectiveFiction : Much!  (In just my opinion, of course.)

Comment: Prior to the bulk of the EU or prequels, much of his popularity came from a combination of his mystique and his boldness in talking to Vader, as well as his apparent reputation and skills. Vader specifically addresses him and tells him not to disintegrate his bounties. He's the only one clever enough to deduce Han's trick to "disappear" off the radar, and he's bold enough to openly question Vader's actions in Cloud City.

Comment: Of course, much of this was tempered slightly by the fact that he went down like a chump in RotJ.

Comment: After the edit, it's no longer opinion-based. Now it's a list question :-(

Comment: @Richard: I'm sorry :( I don't really know how big the EU is. I assumed Boba had a kick-ass role in some spinoff series or something and that's how he became so popular. I was just looking for that!

Comment: @Area51DetectiveFiction - I count at least 10+ TV, Radio and film appearances as well as over 50 books, comics, etc http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Boba_Fett

Comment: @Richard: I'd say to mention the top 3, but that'd be opinion-based. Back to square one.

Comment: @Area51DetectiveFiction - The top 3 would be his appearance in the films and the novelisations (canon). Beyond that, it's EU all the way down.

Comment: top 3 based on what?

Comment: @phantom42: His screen time (or "page time")

Comment: One additional point that *may* have influenced his popularity was that you could not just buy his action figure in a store.  You had to cut several proofs of purchase (5, I think) and then send in a special order for it to be mailed to you.  So rarity of the action figure may have increased popularity, but mostly I think he just looked cool.

Answer (score 5):

There are a number of works that feature Fett in a prominent role in Legends canon (not counting the YA or children's novels):

- The [Bounty Hunter Wars](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Bounty_Hunter_Wars) trilogy, which begins immediately after Fett's escape from the Sarlaac. It also features flashbacks to events around the time of *A New Hope*.
- The [Legacy of the Force](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Legacy_of_the_Force) series, specifically *Bloodlines*, *Sacrifice*, *Revelation*, and *Invincible*. In these,

> Fett seeks revenge for Darth Caedus' murder of his daughter by training Jaina Solo in the ways of the Mandalorians, to give her an unexpected fighting edge.

- [Boba Fett: A Practical Man](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Boba_Fett:_A_Practical_Man) (e-book), which features Boba Fett and the Mandalorians in their work against the Vong. Fett appears only briefly in the main *New Jedi Order* arc.

Fett also appears in the *Fate of the Jedi* arc briefly, but does play a crucial role in the novel *Conviction*.

One set of YA novels that does feature Fett several times is the *Young Jedi Knights* series, specifically the [Diversity Alliance](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Young_Jedi_Knights:_The_Fall_of_the_Diversity_Alliance) arc.

Comment: Was he in Tales of Bounty Hunters? Been a while so I don't recall

Comment: He also had a fairly large presence in Han Solo trilogy, visavi his quest to capture Solo's gf

Comment: @DVK Yes, there's a Fett story in there - there's one for each bounty hunter that appears in ESB, I think. There's also a Fett story in Tales from Jabba's Palace, detailing his escape from the Sarlacc.

Answer (score 1):

A separate answer for **new Disney canon**:

- While Boba Fett the person doesn't yet appear, a new canon book "Aftermath" mentions Jawas on Tatooine selling a Mandalorian armor which was strongly implied the Sarlacc-eaten-Fett owned, to a new Sheriff.

  [This blog post](https://www.bobafettfanclub.com/news/fettpedia/is-that-boba-fetts-armor-post-sarlacc-in-star-wars-aftermath/) covers it in detail, including book quotes

  > From the box, he withdraws a helmet. Pitted and pocked, **as if with some kind of acid**. But still-- he raps his knuckles on it . The Mandalorians knew how to make armor, didn't they? "Look at this," he says, holding it up. "**Mandalorian battle armor. Whole box. Complete set, by the looks of it**. Been through hell and back. I think my boss will appreciate this."
- So far, Fett's status in new canon is unclear but plausibly he survived, just like in the EU/Legends.

  These 2 blog posts cover it: [Schrodinger's Fett](https://www.bobafettfanclub.com/news/fettpedia/schrodingers-fett-the-life-death-paradox-of-boba-fett/) and [Is Boba Fett Dead or Alive?](https://www.bobafettfanclub.com/news/fett-fact-check/is-boba-fett-dead-or-alive/).

  Looks like the most authoritative hint points to [Lucas deciding that Fett is indeed alive](https://www.bobafettfanclub.com/news/fettpedia/j-w-rinzler-confirms-george-lucas-boba-fett-survived-the-sarlacc/) in 2014.
- Just to be clear, any mentions from the Battlefront videogame are NOT considered part of Disney canon and thus don't count. But he does appear there.